# WIX installer - app pool password management

Tags: wix

I got a requirement where I have to send the Application pool identity's user name and password across the server in our environment.

We got few solution as below:

- Write a WXS script which would delete and create application pool with new identity
- Run a script (WMI) which would be able to do the identity change remotely
- Windows Managed service account (MSA)

Out of this 1 and 3 seem to be a better solution but moving towards MSA involves a lot of approvals from business and may not pursued in this urgency.

We need to go for creating WIX package only. Only concern here is I have to put the password as clear text in the WXS file which is a security risk as all the developers who have access to TFS can see the password.

Any idea on how to use the encrypted password in WXS file? So, while installing the MSI, the password needs to be decrypted and set as Identity for the application pool.

Comment: You can define Permission level for this file in the tfs.

Comment: Yeah.That helps..But still , that is not the standard followed in our company. Any suggestion to keep the encrypted password in WXS file would be great